Setting sticky session cookie for specific path in nginx ingress
I have an application that sets cookies for session affinity for a particular path, for example:
/my-resource/123123/sub-resource/2
This works well with the AWS ALB: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/prescriptive-guidance/latest/load-balancer-stickiness/app-cookies-stickiness.html
Which support app based sticky session.
I'm migrating this to an nginx-bases ingress, and want to preserve this behavior. Thus do sticky sessions, where session cookies path is the resource address.
Nginx Ingress does not seems to be support this:
https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/main/docs/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations.md#cookie-affinity
It seems it manages the cookies (so no app based), and not able to configure the path (especially not when it is bases on dynamic ids).
Current setup:
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-expires: "60"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-max-age: "60"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-name: mycookie
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-samesite: None

nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-path seems to support only static paths.
Is there a way to solve this with nginx based ingress?
thank you!!

Custom Lua scripts provide a flexible way to dynamically set session cookie paths based on the request URL. Follow this github issues and this Ingress document which may helps to resolve your issue
